# Getting error when installing react native vector icons

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I am trying to use react native vector icons in my project, but I getting error when installing it.

Below are the STEPS which I was running on my terminal:

STEP-1 : `npm install react-native-elements --save`

NO ERROR ON THIS STEP-1

STEP-2: `npm install react-native-vector-icons --save`

NO ERROR ON THIS STEP-2

STEP-3: `react-native link react-native-vector-icons`

ERROR:

```
react-native : The term 'react-native' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ react-native link react-native-vector-icons
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (react-native:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: which react-native version are you working on?

Comment: 1. `npm install --save react-native-vector-icons` 2. `npx react-native link react-native-vector-icons` and then `cd ios` && `pod install` and then go to `Xcode->in build phases->copy build resources` and delete all the `.ttf` file of `vector-icons` there and boom you are ready to use.

Answer (score 2):

Try `npx react-native link react-native-vector-icons`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using version above 0.60+ you dont need to use link command. Once npm install is done just do

> cd ios && pod install

and it should be fine